# VBA make a smaller array from a larger array by keeping every 4th row using VBA

Tags: vba

I want to create a smaller array from a big array by taking every 4th row of the big array using VBA
    I have defined the big array as 
            dist_in = Range("A3.B903")
    How do I loop thru this array to create the 2nd array?

Thanks, Don

---

Comment: For x=lbound(arr,1) to ubound(arr,1) Step 4...

Answer (score 0):

Quick&dirty - use cells to reference the original and new areas - columns 4&5 will be D & E - alter the numbers to fit.

```
Sub ShrinkIt()

Dim i as long

for i=1 to 225
    cells(i,4)=cells(i*4-1,1)
    cells(i,5)=cells(i*4-1,2)
next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MakeBigArraySmall()

    Dim vaLarge As Variant
    Dim aSmall() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Read in array
    vaLarge = Sheet1.Range("A3:B903").Value

    'set up small array
    ReDim aSmall(1 To (UBound(vaLarge, 1) \ 4) + 1, 1 To UBound(vaLarge, 2))

    'loop through large and write every 4th value to small
    For i = LBound(vaLarge, 1) To UBound(vaLarge, 1) Step 4
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        For j = LBound(vaLarge, 2) To UBound(vaLarge, 2)
            aSmall(lCnt, j) = vaLarge(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    'write small array back out to sheet
    Sheet1.Range("D3").Resize(UBound(aSmall, 1), UBound(aSmall, 2)).Value = aSmall

End Sub
```